# Cómo poner los últimos números decimales pequeños

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap

*Estuve investigando y me encuentro aquí preguntando para ver si puedo lograr una solución final.*

Encontré la forma de que el **precio** se muestre asi: (usando CSS)

```css
.precio:before {
    content: '$ ';
    font-size: 0.8em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.precio:after {
  content: ".00";
  font-size:0.7em;
  vertical-align:top;
  color:aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn bg-dark text-light">

    <span class="precio">300</span>
    
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

En cuanto a qué busco hacer:

Tener en cuenta que **precio** es traído de la base de datos.

```
echo $row['precio'];
```

El campo **precio** es `decimal 7,2`

Puede ser `NULL`

---

Quiero que `$var = $row['precio']` figure como el ejemplo dado arriba (snippet).

**Pregunta:** ¿Alguna forma de obtener el mismo resultado, haciéndolo directamente desde PHP?

Comment: recomendaría **[edit]** la pregunta para reducirlo sólo al problema (este artículo habla de eso: [mcve])... Por ejemplo, eliminaría todo lo referente al administrador, y me dedicaría a explicar que ya tenés el número en una variable y querés imprimirlo desde PHP con ese formato.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como se ha descrito en los comentarios, aunque desde el punto de vista de presentación se consigue el resultado deseado desde el punto de vista semántico puede que sup no sea el elemento adecuado, dejaré la respuesta para que se evalue la mejor opción según el caso de cada quien, y agregaré una opción que es funcionalmente igual y correcta desde el punto de vista semántico.

```css
.decimal {
  position:relative;
  top: -0.5em;
  font-size: 0.83em;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="btn bg-dark text-light">
  <span>300<span class="decimal">45</span></span>
</div>
```

---

No todo debe ser js o css cuando ya hay un elemento para estos casos: [sup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) y es **nativo de HTML**

Código php

```
$numero = -4.25;
$entero = intval($numero);
$decimal = round((abs($numero) - abs($entero)) * 100, 2);

echo '<span>'. $entero . '<sup>' . str_pad($decimal, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '</sup></span>';

echo '<br/>';

$numero = 800.05;
$entero = intval($numero);
$decimal = round((abs($numero) - abs($entero)) * 100, 2);

echo '<span>'. $entero . '<sup>' . str_pad($decimal, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '</sup></span>';
```

Que generaría algo estructuralmente como lo siguiente (clases css omitidas):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="btn bg-dark text-light">
            <span>300<sup>45</sup></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Viendo la autorespuesta del autor, me imagino que le vendría bien que muestres el código PHP para separar la parte entera y decimal del número... quizás agregando el CSS para `sup`

Comment: Aunque correcto, en la [definición de `sup`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#the-sub-and-sup-elements) se especifica que no debe usarse sólo por motivos de representación. Los decimales no tienen por qué ir en superíndice, por lo que realmente éste sería uno de los casos en los que `sup` funciona pero quizás no sea la mejor opción.

Answer (score 6):

Gracias a [@Edgar Gutiérrez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134930/51675) y [@james_bond](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134938/51675) utilizando sus respuestas.

Llegué a una **solución** a mi pregunta. (Muestra lo que quería que muestre)

```
<?php
    // En mi caso p1= $columnas['precio']; p2= $columas['ivatotal'];
     $p1 = 300; 
     $p2 = 0.50;
     $preciot = $p1+$p2;
     $numero = $preciot;
     $entero = intval($numero);
     $decimal = round((abs($numero) - abs($entero)) * 100, 2);
     $nuevo_decimal = str_pad($decimal, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
?>
<span class="precio lblue" data-decimal="<?php echo $nuevo_decimal; ?>">
    <?php echo $entero; ?> 
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.precio:before {
    content: '$ ';
    font-size: 0.8em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.precio:after {
    content: '.'attr(data-decimal);
    font-size:0.7em;
    vertical-align:top;
    color:blue;
}
```

En mi caso, **resultado** (con 2 productos):

[image: Captura con los centavos puestos en diferente formato]

Comment: @Mariano edite mi respuesta. Construida con las 2 respuestas brindadas.

Answer (score 4):

Creo entender, que buscas la manera de traer los decimales, pero pintarlo vía CSS. Esto lo puedes hacer mediante la propiedad `content: attr(data-ejemplo)`, solo tienes que colocar el atributo `data-ejemplo` en el `span` con la cantidad decimal, de esta forma:

```css
.precio:before {
    content: '$ ';
    font-size: 0.8em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.precio:after {
  content: '.'attr(data-decimal);
  font-size:0.7em;
  vertical-align:top;
  color:aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="btn bg-dark text-light">

    <span class="precio" data-decimal="00" >300</span>
    
    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Ahora si lo que buscas es condicionar cuando aparezca 'null' o "0", esto lo debes hacer via servidor o js, pero por css, no es posible.

Espero haber entendido bien, sino comentame a ver si damos con una mejor solución.

Comment: Si, me has ayudado bastante, ahora vere y comprobare con la ayuda del data-decimal y brindare una auto-respuesta con la solución.. si es que funciona :)

Comment: Hola @Edgar. El autor de la pregunta la editó, aclarando mejor lo que necesitaba... Lo que faltaría en tu solución (luego de la edición de la pregunta) es un detalle: mostrar cómo imprimiría desde PHP el valor decimal.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que podrías hacer es separar el numero en dos partes a partir del punto decimal y pintarlo de esta forma:

```
$valor = 3.97;
list($entero,$decimal)=explode('.', $valor);
if( strlen($decimal) == 0) $decimal .= "00";
if( strlen($decimal) == 1) $decimal .= "0";
echo "<span class='precio'>".$entero."</span><sup>.".$decimal."</sup>";
```

Comment: ya está arreglado. Gracias